# Did Goddess Vaisno Devi live without food during her 9 months stay in the cave in Ardhakuwari?

Tags: goddess, devi

The legend of Sri Vaishno Devi temple says, Matha Vaishno Devi stayed in Ardhkuwari, [Katra,Jammu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katra,_Jammu_and_Kashmir) and Kashmir  for 9 months in [this](http://www.maavaishnodevi.net.in/ardhkuwari-temple.htm) cave, so was it without taking any food?

Comment: I have added link to that temple to ur question..You may study that site..Its quite possible that ur question is answered there only..

Comment: Sorry i gave the wrong link :D ..now its corrected..